How to a made query param for refreshed one table with filtered attributes
Context: I have a table of inputs and outputs for a person and with these values ​​I calculate the total hours worked and check whether the total time requirement has been met. Example: Monday = 8 hours
I need to create  query param to update this table with the value of the input type="month" that comes from handlebars.
At the moment I don't have  query param , I tried doing it in the controller and getting obtain the value, but, i dont know return this response from the handlebars and render the attributes
@action
  month(event) {

   
      const filteredEntries = this.model.calculatedEntries.filter(entry => {
        if(entry.attributes.data.substr(0, 7).startsWith(event.target.value) === true) {
          console.log(entry)
        return entry;
          
        }
      });
    
    console.log(filteredEntries[0].attributes)
      return filteredEntries;


  }

Return:{id: '35', type: 'entry', attributes: {…}, relationships: {…}, totalHours: '08:37', …} attributes :  {data: '2024-04-19', dayname: 'Friday', entry1: '07:56:00', exit1: '12:00:00', entry2: '13:27:00', …} hoursRemaining :  "00:37" id :  "35" relationships :  {} totalHours :  "08:37" type :  "entry" [[Prototype]] :  Object
and: data: '2024-04-19', dayname: 'Friday', entry1: '07:56:00', exit1: '12:00:00', entry2: '13:27:00', …}data: "2024-04-19"dayname: "Friday"entry1: "07:56:00"entry2: "13:27:00"exit1: "12:00:00"exit2: "18:00:00"[[Prototype]]: Object
so, I thought of doing this with  query param and updating the model.
This is my handlebar that renders the attributes:
<div class='table-responsive'>
    <table class='table'>
      <thead>
        <tr class='table-dark'>
          <th scope='col'>Data</th>
          <th scope='col'>Dia Semana</th>
          <th scope='col'>Entrada1</th>
          <th scope='col'>Saída1</th>
          <th scope='col'>Entrada2</th>
          <th scope='col'>Saída2</th>
          <th scope='col'>Total de Horas</th>
          <th scope='col'>Saldo final</th>

        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

        {{#each this.model.calculatedEntries as |entry|}}
          <tr>
            <td>{{entry.attributes.data}}</td>
            <td>{{entry.attributes.dayname}}</td>
            <td>{{entry.attributes.entry1}}</td>
            <td>{{entry.attributes.exit1}}</td>
            <td>{{entry.attributes.entry2}}</td>
            <td>{{entry.attributes.exit2}}</td>
            <td>{{entry.totalHours}}</td>
            <td>{{entry.hoursRemaining}}</td>
            <button
              class='btn btn-danger'
              type='button'
              {{on 'click' (fn this.deleteEntry entry)}}
            >Excluir</button>
            <LinkTo
              @route='auth.settings.dailycontrol.edit-entry'
              @model={{entry.id}}
              class='text-decoration-none'
              style='margin-right: 10px;'
            >
              <button
                class='btn btn-primary btn-sm mr-2'
                type='button'
              >Editar</button>
            </LinkTo>

          </tr>
        {{/each}}
      </tbody>
    </table>



  </div>

And this is my route:
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';
import ENV from 'projeto-aspiras-app/config/environment';

import { action } from '@ember/object';
export default class ShowPlanRoute extends Route {
  @service store;
  @service session;







  async model() {
    const { APP } = ENV;
    const { host } = APP;


    let userId = this.session.user.id;

  
    let token = this.session.data.authenticated.token;

  
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);

  
    let requestOptions = {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: headers,
      redirect: 'follow'
    };

    try {

      let settingsResponse = await fetch(`${host}/api/dailycontrol/settings`, requestOptions);
      let settingsData = await settingsResponse.json();


      this.store.pushPayload('setting', settingsData);

      let entriesResponse = await fetch(`${host}/api/dailycontrol/entry/all/${userId}`, requestOptions);
      let entriesData = await entriesResponse.json();
  

      this.store.pushPayload('entry', entriesData);

      let feriadoResponse = await fetch(`${host}/api/dailycontrol/feriado`, requestOptions);
      let feriadoData = await feriadoResponse.json();
    
      this.store.pushPayload('feriado', feriadoData);

    
      let calculatedEntries = entriesData.data.map(entry => {
        let hoursWorked1 = this.calculateHours(entry.attributes.entry1, entry.attributes.exit1);
        let hoursWorked2 = this.calculateHours(entry.attributes.entry2, entry.attributes.exit2);
        let totalHours = hoursWorked1 + hoursWorked2;
    


        let dayName = entry.attributes.dayname;
      
        // Calcular o total de horas para o dia na configuração
        let totalHoursForDay = this.calculateTotalHoursForDay(settingsData.data[0], dayName); 

        let hoursRemaining = totalHours - totalHoursForDay;

        // Validacao para dias de fériado zerar as horas
        if (Number.isNaN(hoursRemaining) === true) {
          hoursRemaining = 0
        } 
        if (Number.isNaN(totalHours) === true) {
          totalHours = 0
        } 
            // Formatando o saldo de horas em hh:mm
        let formattedHoursRemaining = this.formatHours(hoursRemaining);
        let formattedTotalHours = this.formatHours(totalHours);
       // Incluir os valores calculados no objeto entry
        entry.totalHours = formattedTotalHours;
        entry.hoursRemaining = formattedHoursRemaining;           
    

  


            
        return entry;   
      });


      

      return { settings: settingsData, entries: entriesData.data, calculatedEntries, feriado: feriadoData };
    } catch (error) {
   
      console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
    }

    
    return {};
  }

  calculateHours(entryTime, exitTime) {

    let entry = new Date(`01/01/2024 ${entryTime}`);
    let exit = new Date(`01/01/2024 ${exitTime}`);
    let diff = Math.abs(exit - entry);
    return diff / (1000 * 60 * 60); 
  }

  // Método para formatar as horas em hh:mm
  formatHours(hours) {
    let hh = Math.floor(hours);
    let mm = Math.round((hours - hh) * 60);
    return `${hh.toString().padStart(2, '0')}:${mm.toString().padStart(2, '0')}`;
  }

  // Método para calcular o total de horas para o dia na configuração
  calculateTotalHoursForDay(settingsData, dayName) {
  
    let dayKey = dayName;
    if (dayName === null || undefined){
      return ''   
    } else {
         dayKey = dayName.toLowerCase(); // Convertendo o nome do dia para minúsculas
    }
    if (settingsData && settingsData.attributes && settingsData.attributes[dayKey]) {
      return parseInt(settingsData.attributes[dayKey]); // Convertendo o valor para número
    }
    // Retorna 0 se a propriedade não estir presente ou indefinida
    return 0;
    
  }
  
  
}


What i need todo?
Eu tentei retornar os dados do meu controller para o meu handlebars porem, sem sucesso.
